# Installing sound on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: sound

I am currently building a VM with VirtualBox, using Ubuntu Server 14.04, with LXDE desktop and Firefox browser.

My next step is sound installation. There is a lot of info out there, but linux sound is not my strongest subject. It hurts my head. :-(

Please tell me the best way to do this, I'm guessing it's Alsa/OSS via console/apt-get, or something....

Thank you.

RCline7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should follow this steps.
[howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu](http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/)

i tried that's and it's Working.

Comment: @RCline7 Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Comment: Please check my question, I have a similar problem. https://askubuntu.com/questions/910301/cant-get-sound-on-ubuntu-server-minimal